# How do I access a web server on a VirtualBox from the internet?

Tags: networking, web-server, virtualbox, internet

**Scheme:**

1. Direct Internet connection with static IP (**upd**: connected directly to the ISP without any routers).
2. Win Web Server (Win 2008 R2).
3. VirtualBox with guest OS Linux Debian.
4. Web-server on Debian.

**How to configure VirtualBox network?**

Any another solutions for virtualisation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Put virtual box in bridge mode.
- Give your Debian guest an IP address within your LAN.
- Have whatever device holds the static IP address port forward port 80 to the IP address of the Debian guest,

Edit:

Now you have clarified the situation you should take a look at the Network settings. If you have NAT enabled then there is a Port Forwarding button which allows you to configure this and even configures the windows fire wall.

[image]

[image]

Comment: `"Direct Internet connection with static IP"` as i have understand it , he has the Win Server connected directly to the ISP with the static IP.

Comment: If your assumption is correct then that is the device that will have to do the port forwarding.

Comment: I mean, the Win Server connected directly to the ISP with the static IP (colocation in Data Center).